# SQL query displaying float with comma as separator instead of "."

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, floating-point

When I do the following:

```
    declare @x float = 1.5
    select @x
```

The result displayed is `1,5` instead of `1.5`.

But when I `print @x`, it shows the right result: `1.5"`.

This happens also when I query a table with a float field.

I am using sql server 2008 r2, the collation of server and database is sql_latin1_cp1_cs_as.

Is there a configuration to set the right delimiter when querying float fields? 
I would not like to have the cast or replace in all of my queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely don't try to use `REPLACE` to get around this. Display issues should be handled in the display layer whenever possible. If you have a float, treat it as a float, not a string.

The settings should be coming from the regional settings of your computer. I believe that there is a bug that causes decimal data types to not use that setting (always uses period for the decimal point), but for float and money it should be using the regional settings. How to set those will be dependent on your exact OS, but if you search in the Start menu for something like, "change number format" or "regional settings" you should hopefully be able to find it.

Comment: I am runing Windows 7. I look into Control painel -> Region and Language -> Additional Settings -> Numbers -> Decimal Symbol -> changed from "," to "." then went back to the SQL and it worked fine!